# my javascript prevent my code from working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a side nav bar on toggled and by clicking on any point away from the navbar buttons navbar collapse and buttons not working on clicking on it

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($('#wrapper').hasClass('toggled')) {
        $("#body").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: We need a [mcve] which would include the relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: Provide HTML and CSS, there are millions of different way you could have made this. Different markup means different code.

Comment: Any error or similar output? Did you check the browser console?

Comment: I will prepare the HTML and CSS 
console give me nothing

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind a click event after a click event.
I don't see the use of the `$(document).click(function(e){ })`

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});

$("#body").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#wrapper').hasClass('toggled'))
        $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
});
```

And maybe remove the `#` on the `$('#body')` if it needs to be on the `<body>` tag and the `<body>` tag has no id. Because the `#` is an id selector.

Comment: #body is an id, not the tag after trying your code the buttons not working from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are overriding the `click` event handler on your `$("#menu-toggle")` element, you defined in:

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
```

By attaching a `click` event to the `document` in line:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
```

Because `document` is the global element in the page and all other elements are inside of it, so by attaching a `click` event handler to the `document` you are omitting all other `click` handlers on the page.

**Edit:**

Another issue in your code is that you are attaching a `click` event handler inside another `click` event handler:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($('#wrapper').hasClass('toggled')) {
        $("#body").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
        });
    }
});
```

This will attach the second handler, to the `body` element, each time the `document` is clicked, which is a very wrong approach because you are always attaching a new `click` event handler on click of `document` which will lead to bad performance in your appplication.